# Registering with a new account failed

Tags: java, php, android, database-connection

Below is a registration form where user can register a new account, however when I try to sign up it connect to the server, but for some reason it failed to register!
with message from php file (Hmmm Look Like User Already Exist...) however I'm sure that the user doesn't exist in the database table!

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView sign_in_text;
EditText Name,Email,Pass,ConPass;
Button reg_button;
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    sign_in_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
    sign_in_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_register);
    Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_register);
    ConPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_conf);
    reg_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_button);
    reg_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(Name.getText().toString().equals("")|| Email.getText().toString().equals("")|| Pass.getText().toString().equals("")){

                mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Oops something went wrong!");
                mBuilder.setMessage("Please fill all the fields");
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
            else if (!(Pass.getText().toString().equals(ConPass.getText().toString()))){


                mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Oops something went wrong!");
                mBuilder.setMessage("Your passwords are not matching");
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        Pass.setText("");
                        ConPass.setText("");
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }

            else {

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(RegisterActivity.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("register",Name.getText().toString(),Email.getText().toString(),Pass.getText().toString());


            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

And this is the background task where I connect the to server

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
   public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String register_url ="http://justawesome.net/ozone_registration/register.php";

    String login_url ="http://justawesome.net/ozone_registration/login.php";
    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Activity activity;
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity) ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("register")){

            try {
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

                String name = params[1];
                String email = params[2];
                String password = params[3];

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+"-"+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+"-"+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"-"+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = "";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else if (method.equals("login")){

            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =  (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));

                String email,password;
                email = params[1];
                password = params[2];

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+"-"+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"-"+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();



                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = "";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
                }

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            //String response = jsonObject.getString("server_response");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject Jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String code = Jo.getString("code");
            Log.d("code0", code);
            String message = Jo.getString("message");
            Log.d("message", message);

            if(code.equals("reg_true")){

                showDialog("Registration Success", message,code);
                Log.d("code1", code);
            }
            else if(code.equals("reg_false")){

                showDialog("Registration Failed", message,code);
                Log.d("code2", code);
            }

            else if (code.equals("login_true")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AccountActivity.class );
                intent.putExtra("message", message);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (code.equals("login_false")){

                showDialog("Login Error...",message,code);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And this is the php file.

P.S.: I tested the backend and it works fine.

```
<?php

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 require "init.php";

 $query = "SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE email like '$email';";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

        $response = array();
        $code = "reg_false";
        $message = "Hmmm Look Like User Already Exist...";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
    }
    else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO userdb(name,email,password)values('$name','$email','$password');";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


        if(!$result){

        $response = array();
        $code = "reg_false";
        $message = "Some server error occourred.  Try again... ";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
        echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

        }else{

            $response = array();
            $code = "reg_true";
            $message = "Yuoohooo Registration Success... Thank you";
            array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
            echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

        }
    }

 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: What is `$con` in your file?

Comment: it's connection

Comment: Please post your `init.php` file and simply check by making connection to database by echoing the status first.

Comment: <?php

//Define your host here.
$dbServername = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$dbUsername = "rawad_ozoneregur";

//Define your database password here.
$dbPassword = "thisIsNotThePass";

//Define your database name here.
$dbName = "rawad_ozoneregdb";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($con) 
{
echo "connection success";

}
else {

echo "connecction not success";
}


?>

Comment: the above is the init.php i tested and its works I think the problem is in the BackgroundTask.java file.

Comment: I create a test.html file and uploaded it to server it works you can check it at the following link http://justawesome.net/ozone_registration/test.html